# The chat room lives!

Tags: discussion, chat

Me and one or two others (ok [mainly one other](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/97438/aravona)) have been actually chatting, in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-great-outdoors). Honestly it's amazing were having ridiculous amounts of fun...you should all join us so you don't miss out?

Seriously, chat can be a really good way to engage the community (that's you). Come and moan or ask informal questions or whatever.  It'll help make The Great Outdoors a better place (pun intended)

[image]

Comment: Loving the chat room!

Comment: Now I enter the chat room and nobody is there to chat with ;(

Comment: sorry you missed out @EverythingRightPlace. I'm going to make a concious effort to write some *"thoughts"* try and make the chat room a bit more active.

Comment: Chat room is doing very well, staying busy with plenty of on and off topic chat going on, brilliant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer appropriately because I **hate** unanswered questions...

Q: `You should all join us so you don't miss out?`

A: `Yes, I am actually not missing the chat! It's a great opportunity to discuss some important and some even not so important facts!`

Comment: I've just spotted this, ha ha!