# Let's all have a chat in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Following on from a [previous Meta post](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/521/the-chat-room-lives)..

The chat room (I feel) has been a good place for several of the regulars to gather around. I feel it's helped the site grow and kept interest in the site even when the question rate has been low.

Recently we've had a few regulars drop out of the chat room and it's starting to get a little quiet in there. Me and one or two others are pretty much in there 9-5 (GMT) mon-fri but it'd be nice to get some new faces/activity outside of UK time.

So I figured I'd write this post to see if I could drum up some interest.

If anyone has any thoughts, ideas or feedback on this or if they think the chat room could be improved in anyway please post a comment or answer below.

## TL;DR

**Come and join us in [The Base Camp](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) (The TGO chat room)**

Comment: Love our chatroom and I'm in there often! :)

Comment: I like Base camp chatroom as well. Keep up the good work guys!

Comment: Summer holidays and breaks are nearly over in UK, so folks are likely to return soon :-)

Comment: Good point @RoryAlsop

Answer (score 5):

This is an excellent idea! I can't speak highly enough about The Base Camp! Entering a new room can be a bit intimidating, especially when it appears to be a small number of people who've known each other for a while, and are the senior members on the site-no reference to age intended! This invitation is a great way to let people know that there's no clique here, just a group of friends who share a love of the outdoors, enjoy getting to know each other, and want everyone to feel comfortable on the site.

Last June, when I wasn't sure if certain questions would fit here, I dropped in and pinged the one person whose name I knew, and immediately was responded to by four people! I'm shy, have some physical handicaps, and have never done many of the exciting things that are popular at TGO. My new friends made it clear that my questions and I are more than welcome, which gave me the courage to participate, and now I love it here!

I live in Massachusetts, USA, in Eastern Standard Time, which is 4 hours earlier than UTC.  My husband works nights. He leaves around 4 pm, so I do most of my chatting, if any, in the late afternoon and early evening-occasionally later if I'm feeling energetic! I'm around during the day too, just not as frequently.  I should be making more of an effort to chat while the folks from the UK are there, but I keep up by reading the transcripts. We leave notes back and forth too, although I'm not as good at responding as I should be! I'm all for attracting people from new time zones, to increase participation, and to hang out with in real-time!

Definitely check out The Base Camp! It's a fun family formed from a community of strangers, which is a rare and awesome thing!

Comment: Welcome Sue! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Excellent idea mate. I know I am one of the regulars who have had been (forced) away for quite a long time. And, as I returned to my regular job place again today in the morning, I plan to get back in and be active for as long as I can. I have missed TGO and The Base Camp a lot. And, I really don't think I have lost an ounce of interest in the site and the chat room as well. We have a long way to go, long time to discuss and grow :)
Cheers to the chat room.

About timings, I guess its just me and Arrofar who are from Asia. So, usually I will be in here from say 0900 hrs to 1900 hrs IST. Thats GMT+5.30.

See you all!